# "Descriptor is not a socket" exception

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I am getting an exception after disconnecting a socket manually:

> The descriptor is not a socket UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   ClientTCP:OnReceive() (at Assets/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:95)
>   ClientTCP:ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:37) System.Net.Sockets.Worker:Connect()

I thought that when I enable "closed" flag, my "while(!closed) OnReceive()" cycle should stop.

And when that method gets 0 bytes, it should print "Disconnected from server" and set that flag to True.

And that actually worked just like that: I was getting "Disconnected from server"message in Unity.

I haven't changed anything in the code but now upon "_clientSocket.Disconnect(true);" I am getting the mentioned exception.

Could you please take a look at what I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using Bindings;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClientTCP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private byte[] _asyncbuffer = new byte[1024];
    private bool closed;

    public string IP_ADDRESS;
    public int PORT;

    public void ConnectToServer()
    {
        closed = false;
        Debug.Log("Connecting to server...");
        _clientSocket.BeginConnect(IP_ADDRESS, PORT, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _clientSocket);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        _clientSocket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
        while (!closed)
        {
            OnReceive(); //Line 37
        }

    }

    public void DisconnectFromServer()
    {
        _clientSocket.Disconnect(true);

        closed = true;
    }

    private void OnReceive()
    {
        byte[] _sizeinfo = new byte[4];
        byte[] _receivedbuffer = new byte[1024];

        int totalread = 0, currentread = 0;

        try
        {
            currentread = totalread = _clientSocket.Receive(_sizeinfo); //Line 58

            if (totalread <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Disconnected from server");
                closed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                while (totalread < _sizeinfo.Length && currentread > 0)
                {
                    currentread = _clientSocket.Receive(_sizeinfo, totalread, _sizeinfo.Length - totalread, SocketFlags.None);
                    totalread += currentread;
                }

                int messagesize = 0;
                messagesize |= _sizeinfo[0];
                messagesize |= (_sizeinfo[1] << 8);
                messagesize |= (_sizeinfo[2] << 16);
                messagesize |= (_sizeinfo[3] << 24);

                byte[] data = new byte[messagesize];

                totalread = 0;
                currentread = totalread = _clientSocket.Receive(data, totalread, data.Length - totalread, SocketFlags.None);

                while (totalread < messagesize && currentread > 0)
                {
                    currentread = _clientSocket.Receive(data, totalread, data.Length - totalread, SocketFlags.None);
                    totalread += currentread;
                }

                ClientHandleNetworkData.HandleNetworkInformation(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message); //Line 95, here the exception is thrown
            closed = true;
        }
    }
```

ex.ToString() gives the following:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The descriptor is not a socket
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at ClientTCP.OnReceive () [0x0001e] in
>   /Users/nidere/Projects/Unity/OverWaste/Assets/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:58 
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) ClientTCP:OnReceive() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:95)
>   ClientTCP:ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:37) System.Net.Sockets.Worker:Connect()

58 line is:

```
currentread = totalread = _clientSocket.Receive(_sizeinfo);
```

Comment: Which line is line `95` in your script? can you maybe mark it with a comment like `//Here the exception is thrown` within your code snippet?

Comment: The 95 line is the one that prints the exception message: "Debug.Log(ex.Message);"

The 37 line is "OnReceive();" inside a "while(!closed)"cycle

Comment: :D yeah that makes sense sorry ^^ You could try to comment out the `try` and `catch` statements in order to see in which line exactly this error is produced originally. Or use `Debug.Log(ex.ToString())` to also get its stack trace printed

Comment: Great idea, thanks! I've removed the try-catch blocks and now it just breaks the connection without any message (though it should print "disconnected from server"), the exception do not arise.

ex.ToString() gave me almost the same result, I've updated the post with it